# SQL Server - Insert and update specification (Foreign key relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to know if there is any way to write some function or stored procedure in sql server to change the **delete rule** programmatically?

Example: I have to change the delete rule from **Cascade** to **none** or vice versa but I don't want to do graphically.

Because I have to do quite often and want to revert it back to its initial stage.

Comment: You need to drop and then create the constraint. If you don't want to do it via GUI then you have to write `ALTER` scripts

Comment: @Abhishek is there any way to create a UI in linq for sql to generate constraints programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a foreign key already called fk_table1_table2 with cascade none.
You would have to drop the constraint and then recreate a constraint with cascade:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2] FOREIGN KEY([Table2])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table2] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2]
GO
```

This is generated from ssms. You can do this like here:
[image: Generate Drop and Create Key]

You can right click on any Key and generate the code for you ;)

Comment: is there any way to create a UI in linq for sql to generate constraints programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter a foreign key constraint to change the cascade option, you will have to drop it and create it again with the option you want. Make sure to set it on a transaction as you don't want inconsistent data getting stuck in the middle of the change.

The alter commands of an example:

```
ALTER TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [ConstraintName]

ALTER TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [ConstraintName] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ColumnName]) REFERENCES [SchemaName].[YetAnotherTableName]([ColumnName]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: is there any way to create a UI in linq for sql to generate constraints programmatically?

Comment: @user2983359 you can ask that as a new question, providing some insight to your motives.